# PHP htmlentities() not working as expected

Tags: php, character-encoding, special-characters, html-entities

I'm having a problem with htmlentities()

```
$txt = "árbol";
echo $txt; // outputs: árbol
echo htmlentities($txt); // outputs: Ã¡rbol (&Atilde;&iexcl;rbol)
```

The second echo should output **árbol (&aacute;)**

I'm using utf-8:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

What's going on? Thank you!

Comment: It's worth noting that this shouldn't normally be necessary to do. If you're having trouble with broken characters, adjust your encodings instead. Somewhat related: [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the third parameter of `htmlentities()` which tells the charset to use. Because of you don't set it, the default is used and the default is ISO-8859-1, not UTF-8.

> Like htmlspecialchars(), it takes an optional third argument charset which defines character set used in conversion. Presently, the ISO-8859-1 character set is used as the default.

Just to clarify, this is the function signature:

```
string htmlentities ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 [, string $charset [, bool $double_encode = true ]]] )
```

and here you'll find the official doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php