# htmlentities converts trademark into &acirc;�&cent;

Tags: php, xml, html-entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP htmlentities() not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434913/php-htmlentities-not-working-as-expected)

I am using htmlentities to convert a trademark symbol into the htmlentity, but it is giving me `&acirc;�&cent;`. Am I doing something wrong

here is my code

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'; ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:c="http://www.base.google.com/cns/1.0">
<channel>
<title>Spray Foam Systems</title>
<link>http://www.sprayfoamsys.com/store/</link>
<description>Spray Foam Rigs, Spray Foam Equipment, Sprayfoam Parts and Supplies.</description>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect(REMOVED) or die(mysql_error());
    if (!$con)
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    mysql_select_db("sprayfoa_store", $con);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $con);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` WHERE `visibility` = 4 ORDER BY entity_id asc")
    or die(mysql_error());
?>
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
?>
<item>
<g:id><?php echo $row['entity_id']; ?></g:id>
<title><?php echo htmlentities($row['name']); ?></title>
<description><?php echo htmlentities(str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n"), ' ', $row['short_description'])); ?></description>
<g:google_product_category>Business &amp; Industrial &gt; Construction</g:google_product_category>
<g:product_type>Spray Foam Parts &amp; Supplies &gt; Fusion AP Parts</g:product_type>
<link>http://sprayfoamsys.com/store/<?php echo $row['url_path']; ?></link>
<g:image_link>http://sprayfoamsys.com/store/media/catalog/product<?php echo $row['small_image']; ?></g:image_link>
<g:condition>new</g:condition>
<g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
<g:price><?php echo $row['price']; ?></g:price>
<g:brand><?php $entity_id = $row['entity_id']; $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE entity_id = '$entity_id' AND attribute_id = '127'") or die(mysql_error()); while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) { echo $row2['value']; } ?></g:brand>
<g:mpn><?php echo $row['sku']; ?></g:mpn>
</item>
<?php
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: You need the third parameter to [`htmlentities($str, $flags, "UTF-8")`](http://php.net/htmlentities)

Comment: @Brett You really, *really* should use a DOMDocument to build the XML. It may be more code, but building XML like you do now is plain wrong. Also, find out about SQL joins, this query inside the loop is entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), when not feeding this function with ISO-8859-1 strings, you need to provide a charset:

```
echo htmlentities($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

**Update March 2015**: Note that since this answer, the default character set this function uses has been changed for different versions:

- PHP < 5.4: `ISO-8859-1`
- PHP 5.4 & 5.5: `UTF-8`
- PHP >= 5.6: the `default_charset` setting (which is very welcome, and how it should have been in the first place).

Comment: Nice magic! Works for me, a PHP noob.

Answer (score 0):

Try to explore the additional parameters of `htmlentities()` they may be helpful

https://www.php.net/htmlentities