# Fetching strings with special alphabet from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a php variable which has its value set from an HTML form.
The value of the variable is

```
$x = rueFrédéricMistral
```

As you may see it has a special alphabet (e_tilda) in it.

Now when I echo x, it gives me the following: `rueFr�d�ricMistral`

I am not sure how to echo the original name.
I tried the function `htmlspecialchars()` but it didn't work.
On reading, what I understood that the function does not suit my case.

Can anyone help me on this please.

Thanks in advance.
Neeraj

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting special characters out of a MySQL database with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892610/getting-special-characters-out-of-a-mysql-database-with-php)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: Code enhancement

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this

```
echo htmlentities($x);
```

and also you can used this

for server side

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
?>
```

for client side

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $x = "rueFrédéricMistral";
            echo $x;
        ?>
    </body>
```

Comment: I tried this and it is not working. However, the issue comes when I try to use $x in javascript. I wrote the following code in javascript: var abcd = <?php echo json_encode($x); ?>; alert(abcd).... But I get null in the alert message

Answer (score 0):

There is at least 3 possible reasons:

1. (most likely) you have incorrect charset definition into your html page, make sure that you have something like `<meta charset="utf8"/>` inside `<head>` section of your page
2. It is possible that you have defined wrong charset for your database connection. Refer to documentation for functions / library that you're using to connect to database
3. (unlikely) It is possible that contents inside database is broken by itself e.g. due to migration / inserting using invalid charset.