# why does htmlentities() convert the symbol: ´ into â€™? Shouldn't it convert into the html entity name: &acute;?

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP htmlentities() not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434913/php-htmlentities-not-working-as-expected)

I'm confused as to why it is converted into strange characters as opposed to just `&acute;`  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the second `flags` argument - http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php, e.g.

```
htmlentities( $string, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, "UTF-8" );
```